# Passing open array into an anonymous function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, anonymous-methods

What is the least wasteful way (i.e. avoiding copying if at all possible) to pass the content of an open string array into an anonymous function and from there into another function that expects an open array?

The problem is that open arrays cannot be captured in anonymous functions in Delphi XE2.

This illustrates the problem:

```
procedure TMyClass.DoSomething(const aStrings: array of string);
begin
  EnumItems(
    function (aItem: string) : Boolean
    begin
      Result := IndexText(aItem, aStrings) >= 0;
    end);
end;
```

The compiler complains: "Cannot capture symbol 'aStrings'".

An obvious solution is to make a copy of aStrings in a dynamic array and capture that. But I don't want to make a copy. (While my specific problem involves a string array and making a copy would only copy the pointers not the string data itself due to reference counting, it would also be instructive to learn how to solve the problem for an arbitrarily large array of a non-reference counted type.)

So I tried capturing instead a `PString` pointer to the first string in aStrings and an `Integer` value of the length. But then I couldn't figure out a way to pass these to `InsertText`.

One other constraint: I want it to be possible to call `DoSomething([a, b, c])`.

Is there a way to do this without making a copy of the array, and without writing my own version of `IndexText`, and without being hideously ugly? If so, how?

For the sake of this question I've used `IndexText`, but it would be instructive to find a solution for a function that could not be trivially rewritten to accept a pointer and length parameter instead of an open array.

An acceptable answer to this question would be: No, you can't do that (at least not without making a copy or rewriting `IndexText`) though if so I'd also like to know the fundamental reason why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to copy the array then you should change the signature of DoSomething to take a `TArray<string>` instead. You of course have to change the caller side if you are passing the elements directly (only since XE7 you can pass dynamic arrays in the same way) - like `DoSomething([a, b, c])` i mean.

My advice is not to mess around with some internal pointers and stuff, especially not for an open array.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling `DoSomething([a, b, c])` :-(

Comment: @IanGoldby: Then create a dynamic `TArray<string>` and pass that. In XE7 that can be done with: `myArray := [a, b, c];`, otherwise it can be done using the Create syntax: `myArray := TArray<string>.Create(a, b, c);`, but note that that is not very performant. But OTOH, an open array parameter constructor is not very performat either. Make sure that the parameter is `const`, to avoid any copying.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this without making a copy. Open arrays cannot be captured as you have found, and you cannot get the information into the anonymous method without capture. You must capture, in general, because you need to extend the life of the variable.

So, you cannot do this with an open array and avoid a copy. You could instead:

1. Switch from open array to a dynamic array, `TArray<string>`.
2. Make a copy of the array. You would not be copying the string data, just the array of references to the strings.

Comment: You can capture a pointer to the array's first element (and not make a copy), but then you no longer have an open array to pass to `IndexText`. It was this second part that I thought might have a solution. It sounds like you are saying there isn't.

Comment: The anon method may live beyond the scope of the open array. Then your pointer is invalid. That's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: OK, I know about the lifetime issue (and why the compiler won't capture the open array parameter). I'm only concerned about the specific case where the anon method *won't* outlive the array and wondered if there is a syntax to make a pointer and a length parameter look like an open array to `IndexText` (or some similar 'trick').

Comment: You can hack it around if you want but it's not worth it. Use `TArray<string>`.

Comment: Thanks. If there's no simple solution then any hack would be unbearably ugly. I decided to accept Stefan's answer because it mentioned XE7 and had a useful comment from Rudy attached.

Comment: OK. I thought you were using XE2.

Comment: I am, but it could be useful to someone else.